# C++11: GCC 4.8 static thread_local std::unique_ptr undefined reference

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, thread-local-storage

I need to store a unique pointer for every thread that will be accessed through a macro. I thought I should solve this with a singleton and static thread_local std::unique_ptr objects. Here is a simplified version of the code:

## main.cpp

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

#include "yay.hpp"

mutex coutMutex;

void yay(int id)
{
    int* yayPtr = getYay();

    // I know this is bad
    coutMutex.lock();
    cout << "Yay nr. " << id << " address: " << yayPtr << endl;
    coutMutex.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    vector<thread> happy;
    for(int i = 0; i < thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++)
    {
        happy.push_back(thread(yay, i));
    }

    for(auto& smile : happy)
    {
        smile.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## yay.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef BE_HAPPY
#define BE_HAPPY

#include <memory>
class Yay
{
    private:
        static thread_local std::unique_ptr<int> yay;
        Yay() = delete;
        Yay(const Yay&) = delete;
        ~Yay() {}
    public:
        static int* getYay()
        {
            if(!yay.get())
            {
                yay.reset(new int);
            }
            return yay.get();
        }
};

#define getYay() Yay::getYay()

#endif
```

## yay.cpp

```cpp
#include "yay.hpp"

thread_local std::unique_ptr<int>  Yay::yay = nullptr;
```

If I compile this with gcc 4.8.1:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -o yay main.cpp yay.cpp
```

I get:

```
/tmp/cceSigGT.o: In function `_ZTWN3Yay3yayE':
main.cpp:(.text._ZTWN3Yay3yayE[_ZTWN3Yay3yayE]+0x5): undefined reference to `_ZTHN3Yay3yayE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was hoping I might get more information from clang, however it works perfectly fine with clang 3.4:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -pthread -o yay main.cpp yay.cpp
```

And running the program yields the result I was expecting:

```
Yay nr. 2 address: 0x7fcd780008e0
Yay nr. 0 address: 0x7fcd880008e0
Yay nr. 1 address: 0x7fcd800008e0
Yay nr. 3 address: 0x7fcd700008e0
Yay nr. 4 address: 0x7fcd740008e0
Yay nr. 5 address: 0x7fcd680008e0
Yay nr. 6 address: 0x7fcd6c0008e0
Yay nr. 7 address: 0x7fcd600008e0
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, is it not possible to have static thread_local unique_ptr objects? It works with simple types like int or 'naked' pointers.

## Edit:

It's possible that this is a bug that is related to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55800

## Edit2:

Workaround 1: compile the one file with clang (yay.cpp)

Workaround 2 (horrible and unportable): compile yay.cpp to assembly first, add

```
.globl _ZTWN3Yay3yayE
_ZTWN3Yay3yayE = __tls_init
```

to the assembly file, compile to object file, link with the rest

Comment: Is it possible that the preprocessor substitution of `getYay()` is messing you up?

Comment: No, it doesn't work if I remove the #define and call Yay::getYay() directly.

Comment: In your bug report you show a much reduced version of your code and a possible workaround. Maybe you could post that as an answer.

Comment: I don't know - the "workaround" is just messing around with the assembly output. The proper solution would be messing around with what generates the assembly and sending in a patch. I don't know enough about gcc to do that however. But I think I'll edit the post with the workaround

Comment: GCC 4.8 is old and its C++11 support is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

I experimented with this by defining a do-nothing ctor for Yay in Yay.hpp:

```
- Yay() = delete;
+ Yay() {}
```

When I did that, the error message became:

```
/tmp/cc8gDxIg.o: In function `TLS wrapper function for Yay::yay':
main.cpp:(.text._ZTWN3Yay3yayE[_ZTWN3Yay3yayE]+0x5): undefined reference to `TLS init function for Yay::yay'
```

That led me to [GCC bug 55800](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55800). The bug exists in GCC versions up through 4.8.2, and is fixed in 4.8.3 and 4.9. In discussion threads I found on duplicate [GCC bug 59364](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59364), the decision has been made not to back port the fix. Therefore, your assembler hack appears to be the only solution available until you move to 4.9.

Answer (score 1):

For me it turned out I was linking with `-Wl,--image-base,0x14000000` and removing that or changing it to `-Wl,--image-base,0x10000000` and the problem went away.  No idea what is actually going on here...

I believe I was bumping up into gcc bug [64697](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64697) since it was indeed a static thread_local -std=c++11.  It worked in 32 bit but not 64? Very odd...gcc 8.2.0 mingw w64 cross compile:

```
 librtmfp.a(IOSocket.o):IOSocket.cpp:(.text+0x46c4): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `TLS init function for Base::ThreadQueue::_PCurrent'
```

Original hint [here](https://bitbucket.org/berkeleylab/upcxx/issues/58/regression-on-cygwin-opt-undefined-symbol).