# using extern thread_local in C++11 on Cygwin/AMD64

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cygwin, thread-local-storage

I am having linking issues when using `thread_local` keyword in Cygwin with its GCC 4.8.3 and GCC 4.9.2. This is derived from log4cplus. The test case is split into three files:

File `def.hxx`:

```
#include <string>

namespace N
{
  struct S { std::string str; };
  // extern declaration in a header
  extern thread_local S * ptd;

  // accessing the extern declared ptd here
  inline
  S * get_ptd ()
  {
    if (! ptd)
      ptd = new S;
    return ptd;
  }
} // namespace N
```

File `def.cxx`:

```
#include "def.hxx"

namespace N
{
  // definition of ptd
  thread_local S * ptd = nullptr;
} // namespace N
```

File `use.cxx`:

```
#include "def.hxx"

namespace N
{
  __declspec(dllexport)
  void * foo ()
  {
    // invoking inline get_ptd() function to get the value in ptd
    return get_ptd ();
  }
}
```

Now, when I compile each `.cxx` with `g++ -std=gnu++11 -fvisibility=hidden -c use.cxx def.cxx` and then try to link with `g++ -shared -o cygtest.dll use.o def.o`, I get the following error from linker:

```
use.o:use.cxx:(.text$_ZTWN1N3ptdE[_ZTWN1N3ptdE]+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `TLS init function for N::ptd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `nm -C ./def.o` output confirms that:

```
`--> nm -C ./def.o
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000008 r __emutls_t._ZN1N3ptdE
0000000000000000 D __emutls_v._ZN1N3ptdE
0000000000000000 r std::piecewise_construct
```

As you can see, the `ptd` thread-local variable initialization function is not defined anywhere. The `use.o` references this initialization function (see bottom of the listing):

```
`--> nm -C ./use.o
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 i .drectve
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 p .pdata$_ZN1N1SC1Ev
0000000000000000 p .pdata$_ZN1N7get_ptdEv
0000000000000000 p .pdata$_ZTWN1N3ptdE
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$.refptr.__emutls_v._ZN1N3ptdE
0000000000000000 r .rdata$.refptr._ZTHN1N3ptdE
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 R .refptr.__emutls_v._ZN1N3ptdE
0000000000000000 R .refptr._ZTHN1N3ptdE
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 t .text$_ZN1N1SC1Ev
0000000000000000 t .text$_ZN1N7get_ptdEv
0000000000000000 t .text$_ZTWN1N3ptdE
0000000000000000 A .weak._ZTHN1N3ptdE._ZN1N1SC1Ev
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000000 r .xdata$_ZN1N1SC1Ev
0000000000000000 r .xdata$_ZN1N7get_ptdEv
0000000000000000 r .xdata$_ZTWN1N3ptdE
                 U __emutls_get_address
                 U __emutls_v._ZN1N3ptdE
                 U __gxx_personality_seh0
                 U __real__ZdlPv
                 U __real__Znwm
                 U _Unwind_Resume
                 U operator delete(void*)
0000000000000000 T N::S::S()
0000000000000000 T N::foo()
0000000000000000 T N::get_ptd()
                 U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()
                 U operator new(unsigned long)
0000000000000000 r std::piecewise_construct
                 w TLS init function for N::ptd
0000000000000000 T TLS wrapper function for N::ptd
```

Now, this code seems to work well on Linux with both GCC and Clang.

- Is this a GCC problem on Cygwin?
- Am I using `extern thread_local` wrong?

My experiments show that not using the `extern` keyword seems to fix the issue. But I am not sure if that does not introduce two `ptd` thread-local variables in two TUs.

### UPDATE

I have created a [GCC bug report for this.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64697)

Comment: There seems to be a very similar [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59364) for GCC 4.8.2. But it could be something different since it's marked as resolved in GCC 4.9.0

Comment: @manlio: That looks like the same area but not the same bug.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432632/c11-gcc-4-8-static-thread-local-stdunique-ptr-undefined-reference